# jquery with json - getting images

Tags: jquery, html, json, dynamic, flickr

im trying to wrap the img + p elements in one div, but for some reason all the elements created in **each div**... what am i doing wrong ?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=**myAPI**&tags=**myTAG**&per_page=20 ";
     var src;
     $.getJSON(url + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function (data) {
         $.each(data.photos.photo, function (i, item) {
             src = "http://farm" + item.farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + item.server + "/" + item.id + "_" + item.secret + "_m.jpg";
             $("<div class='test'></div>").appendTo(".wrap");
             $("<img/>").attr("src", src).attr("class", "titleBox").appendTo(".test");
             $('<p>', { class: 'titleBox', text: item.title }).appendTo(".test");
         });
     });
```

i want it to look like this :

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="test">
<img src="#"/>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
 <div class="test">
  <img src="#"/>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
<img src="#"/>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the json returned by the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an id to div, something like:

```
$.each(data.photos.photo, function (i, item) {
         src = "http://farm" + item.farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + item.server + "/" + item.id + "_" + item.secret + "_m.jpg";
         $("<div class='test' id='test" + i.toString() + "'></div>").appendTo(".wrap");
         $("<img/>").attr("src", src).attr("class", "titleBox").appendTo("#test" + i.toString());
         $('<p>', { class: 'titleBox', text: item.title }).appendTo("#test" + i.toString());
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're appending to `.test`, you're not specifying which `.test` to go to, so it automatically takes the first element. You have an index in your `.each`, use it:

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", src).attr("class", "titleBox").appendTo(".test:eq(" + i + ")");
$('<p>', { class: 'titleBox', text: item.title }).appendTo(".test:eq(" + i + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

All your div's have same class "test" and you are using this class as selector in  appendTo(".test"), 
Hence all elements get appended to first div since the selector condition is met.

Solution : 
Use "id" as selector in appendTo("#id") this identifies div uniquely.
(You can use the count in loop as id)